# Flask-mail attachments error - 'dict' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python, email, flask, email-attachments, flask-mail

The exception is raised when I try to attach a PNG image to my email.

**Here is the email method:**

```py
def send_mail(recipient, subject, message, bcc_mail, attachment=None):
    mail = Mail(app)

    try:
        msg = Message(subject,
                    sender=("Jane Doe", "jane@example.com"),
                    recipients=[recipient],
                    bcc=[bcc_mail])
        if attachment:
            try:
                with app.open_resource(attachment) as f:
                    msg.attach("registration-qr-code.png", "image/png", f.read(), 'inline', headers={'Content-ID': '<qr_image>'})
                    msg.body = render_template('email.html', message=message, image="cid:qr_image")
            except Exception as e:
                print("send_mail.attachment exception: {}".format(e))
        mail.send(msg)
    except:
        print("send_mail exception:\n{}".format(traceback.format_exc()))
    return
```

**And this is how I generate the attachment:**

```py
def make_qr(data):
    data = strip_emoji(data)
    data = strip_html(data)

    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=1,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
        box_size=6,
        border=8,
    )
    qr.add_data(data)
    qr.make(fit=True)

    img = qr.make_image(image_factory=PymagingImage)
    temp = BytesIO()
    temp.name = "QR.png"
    img.save(temp)
    temp.seek(0)

    qr_image = {'photo': temp.getvalue()}
    return qr_image
```

I am not sure where to even start looking. Tried Flask-mail documentation, but there is no sufficient information available on attachments.

Comment: What is the exception which is raised?

Comment: `Python AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'startswith'`. Raised when trying `msg.attach()`.

Answer (score 0):

My bad. The object returned by `make_qr` is a dictionary (`qr_image = {'photo': temp.getvalue()}`) and not an image file.

Passing it into `send_mail` as a dict, the following change to the code fixes it.

```py
msg.attach("registration-qr-code.png", "image/png", attachment['photo'], 'inline', headers=[['Content-ID','<qr_image>'],])
```

I also had to change `headers={'Content-ID': '<qr_image>'}` to `headers=[['Content-ID','<qr_image>'],]`. Probably a bug in Flask-mail.